# Issue with XSD will not allow me to have multiple values for "CustomData" field.

Tags: xml, xsd

Good morning SO -

I am new to xsd and I'm running into a problem with my "customdata" complex type.
It will not allow me to have multiple values for CustomData. For example CustomValue should be more than 1, but it's preventing me from having more than one "CustomValue"..

Why is this? I'm trying to relate "CustomData" to individual letters.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://fult.com/FFCLetters.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://fult.com/FFCLetters.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
  <xs:attributeGroup name="AG_Address">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Property Address
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="Address1" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Address2" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="City" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="State" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
          <xs:minLength value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="ZIP" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="10" />
          <xs:minLength value="5" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  
  <xs:attributeGroup name="AG_Person">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Property Owner Information
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="TaxID" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="11"/>
          <xs:minLength value="9"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  
  <xs:complexType name="CT_Payment">
    <xs:attribute name="ProcessedDate" type="xs:date" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="EffectiveDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="PrincipalAmount" type="xs:double" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="InterestAmount" type="xs:double" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TotalAmount" type="xs:double" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_CreditCounselingAgency">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Current Credit Counseling Agency for Property Owner.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AG_Address" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_CreditCounselingAgencies">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Possible Credit Counseling Agencies. 
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="CreditCounselingAgency" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="CT_CreditCounselingAgency"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_PaymentHistory">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Property Owner Payment History.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Payment" type="CT_Payment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="NoHistoryMessage" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="BeginningDate" use="required" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:attribute name="EndingDate" use="required" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="CT_Account">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Aggregation of Account Data
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PaymentHistory" type="CT_PaymentHistory" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="AccountNumber" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AccountID" use="optional" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:attribute name="RecordDate" use="required" type="xs:date"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_Recipient">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AG_Person" />
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AG_Address" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_Recipients">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Person" type="CT_Recipient" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="CT_Property">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Owners" type="CT_Recipients" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="CreditCounselingAgencies" type="CT_CreditCounselingAgencies" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="AG_Address" />
    <xs:attribute name="ParcelID" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="CountyName" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_LetterFile">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Letter" type="CT_Letter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_Letter">    
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Account" type="CT_Account" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Property" type="CT_Property" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Recipients" type="CT_Recipients" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="CustomData" type="CT_Custom" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:all>    
    <xs:attribute name="RequestID" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="CertifiedMail" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_Custom">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="CustomValues" type="CT_CustomData" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="50" />
          <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CT_CustomData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="CustomValue"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:element name="LetterFile" type="CT_LetterFile" />
</xs:schema>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LetterFile xmlns="http://fult.com/FFCLetters.xsd" Count="2">
  
  <Letter RequestID="12">
    <Account AccountNumber="1234567890" AccountID="234" RecordDate="2015-03-31">
      <PaymentHistory Count="1" NoHistoryMessage="No Payment Activity" BeginningDate="2014-01-01" EndingDate="2015-12-31">
      </PaymentHistory>
    </Account>
    <Recipients>
      <Person Name="Dan Hollinger" Address1="3467 Main St" City="Conestoga" State="PA" ZIP="17516"/>
      <Person Name="Nicole Osgood" Address1="123 Main St" Address2="PO Box 12" City="Lititz" State="PA" ZIP="17543-6546"/>
    </Recipients>
    <Property Address1="213 Valleybrook Dr" City="Lancaster" State="PA" ZIP="17601">
      <Owners>
        <Person Name="Jenn Hollinger" Address1="3467 Main St" City="Conestoga" State="PA" ZIP="17516" />
      </Owners>
    </Property>
  </Letter>
  
  
  <Letter RequestID="13">        
    <Account AccountNumber="1234567890" AccountID="234" RecordDate="2015-03-31">
      <PaymentHistory Count="1" NoHistoryMessage="No Payment Activity" BeginningDate="2014-01-01" EndingDate="2015-12-31">
        <Payment Description="Payment 1" EffectiveDate="2014-02-01" TotalAmount="354.54"/>
      </PaymentHistory>
    </Account>
        
    <Recipients>
      <Person Name="Dan Hollinger" Address1="3467 Main St" City="Conestoga" State="PA" ZIP="17516"/>
      <Person Name="Nicole 1Osgood" Address1="123 Main St" Address2="PO Box 12" City="Lititz" State="PA" ZIP="17543-6546"/>
    </Recipients>
        
    <Property Address1="213 Valleybrook Dr" City="Lancaster" State="PA" ZIP="17601">
      <Owners>
        <Person Name="Jenn Hollinger" Address1="3467 Main St" City="Conestoga" State="PA" ZIP="17516" />
      </Owners>
    </Property>
        
    <CustomData Count="4">
      <CustomValues>
        <CustomValue Name="BankOriginating" Value="The Peoples Bank of Elkton" />
        <CustomValue Name="DateFrom" Value="07/01/13" />
        <CustomValue Name="DateTo" Value="06/29/15" />
        <CustomValue Name="lienPosition" Value="1" />
      </CustomValues>
    </CustomData>
</Letter>
</LetterFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a `maxOccurs` for `CustomValue`. Which means the default of 1 is used.

You should specify `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.